# Java: unable to access static singleton method

Tags: java, static, singleton

i am facing one problem.i have a class named "ReportingService" and it should be singleton and is is extending "CommonService".

```
package MyApp.Services.ReportingService;

public class ReportingService extends CommonService {

    private static ReportingService instance = null;

    public static ReportingService getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ReportingService();
        }
        return instance;   

    }
}
```

and to access this class in other class i am using

```
package MyApp.Services.WebReportingService;
@WebMethod(operationName = "registerUDP")
    public boolean registerUDP(
            @WebParam(name = "Friendly Name") String friendlyName,
            @WebParam(name = "Username") String username,
            @WebParam(name = "Password") String password,
            @WebParam(name = "Communication Protocol") CommunicationProtocol communicationProtocol,
            @WebParam(name = "IP Address") String ipAddress,
            @WebParam(name = "Port") int port) {

        Consumer client = new Consumer(friendlyName, username, password, communicationProtocol, ipAddress, port);

ReportingService rs = ReportingService.
        return true;

    }
```

in "ReportingService rs = ReportingService." it is not showing me **getInstance()** method of ReportingService class. I also imported correct packages.

**NOTE: both classes are in different packages.**

Comment: Have you imported ReportingService?

Comment: But even in the IDE does not show the method, can you add it manually and compile the code?

Comment: looks as you just have auto-complete problem in IDE... try to type ReportingService.getInstance() and see whether you have compilation errors

Comment: Is that the exact code in the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your package names are broken. You seem to have the name of the class at the end of the package - but the name of the class only appears when you import.

So you would have :

```
package myApp.Services;

public class ReportService extends CommonService {/* code goes here */}
```

but then you would include:

```
import myApp.Services.ReportService;
```

Same goes for the WebReportingService. The `package` statement should not include the class name

Edit: if you actually want `ReportService` in package `myApp.Services.ReportService`, then you need to import `myApp.Services.ReportService.ReportService` (or, alternatively, `myApp.Services.ReportService.*`, but this is not recommended unless you need many classes from the package)

Comment: still unable to access. i tried complete class name in import statement on WebReportingService

Comment: try writing the whole package name in the code; something like: `myApp.Services.ReportService.ReportService rs = myApp.Services.ReportService.ReportService.getInstance()` . Also check the `Consumer` class, there seems to be an issue with that as well (it doesn't find the `Observer` class, possibly another import blunder)

Answer (score 3):

Change as follows:

```
package MyApp.Services.ReportingService;  // FIXME - Make package names lowercase!!
                                          // FIXME - Loopy package name

public class ReportingService extends CommonService {

    private static ReportingService instance = null;

    private ReportingService() { }

    public static synchronized ReportingService getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ReportingService();
        }
        return instance;   

    }
}
```

and

```
import MyApp.Services.ReportingService.ReportingService; 

package MyApp.Services.WebReportingService ; 
                        // FIXME - Make package names lowercase!!
                        // FIXME - Loopy package names.

public class WebReportingService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "registerUDP")
    public boolean registerUDP(
            @WebParam(name = "Friendly Name") String friendlyName,
            @WebParam(name = "Username") String username,
            @WebParam(name = "Password") String password,
            @WebParam(name = "Communication Protocol") CommunicationProtocol communicationProtocol,
            @WebParam(name = "IP Address") String ipAddress,
            @WebParam(name = "Port") int port) {

        Consumer client = new Consumer(friendlyName, username, password,
                                       communicationProtocol, ipAddress, port);

        ReportingService rs = ReportingService.getInstance();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note: depending on which packages the `Consumer` and `CommunicationProtocol` classes are defined in, you may need to import them; e.g. add these lines before the `package` line.

```
import some.package.Consumer;
import some.other.package.CommunicationProtocol;
```

Note 2: your current choice of package names has some seriously style issues.

- package names should be all lowercase
- the prefix of your package names should be the (reversed) DNS-style identifier for your company, organization, whatever; e.g. `in.com.yourcompany...`.  Note, there are very good reasons form this convention!!
- `MyApp` / `myapp` is content free and shouldn't be used
- `services.reportingservice` is redundant / verbose; e.g. use `services.reporting` instead
- using the same name as a class and package name is redundant / verbose
- unless there are lots of classes in the `reporting` and `webreporting` packages, they probably should be folded into one package.  Lots of packages with 1 or 2 classes in them is not helpful.

Comment: these two classes are in different packages

Comment: So do you really have a classes called MyApp.Services.WebReportingService.WebReportingService and 
MyApp.Services.ReportingService.ReportingService ??? That seems a bit loopy to me.

Comment: yes there are classes. look "MyApp.Services.ReportingService" is package name and "ReportingService" is class in this package. so that when i import this package i am writing "MyApp.Services.ReportingService.ReportingService"

Comment: Changed per your comments.  Try again.

Comment: +1 for the `synchronized` getInstance()! Also, the singleton needs a declared `private` constructor (just in case that's the whole code).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to import the ReportingService class at the top of your source file, like so:

```
import MyApp.Services.ReportingService.ReportingService;
```

*Edit:* The second code snippet is also lacking a class declaration. If this is the full source, it cannot compile.

*Another edit based on compiler output:* It would also help if you had the `xx.xx.Java.Common.DesignPattern.ObserverPattern.Observer` class on the classpath that the `Consumer`class seems to depend on.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be sure, but I've seen this kind of problem happening when the imported classes are outdated with the code.

This can happen on different IDEs, there's no straightforward solution: Maybe cleaning all classes and compiling them again?

Answer (score 0):

I would try typing getInstance() by hand, as others have suggested in their comments. That should work. The reason I believe your IDE will not show you the method after typing the dot (.) could be simply because of the following return true. It's reading

```
ReportingService rs = ReportingService.return true;
```

which it considers broken code and therefore will not provide code-completion.